# Can I get some help/example on how to get the file translation progress percentage from Forge by using webhook API in C#?

Tags: c#, webhooks, autodesk-forge, forge

Can I get some help/example on how to get the file translation progress percentage from Forge by using web-hook API in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many samples on https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge. For C# examples around webhook, try https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge?q=webhook&type=&language=c%23.

In order to track the progress of your file translation, you can simply create a webhook for the [extraction.updated](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.updated/) event, and then use the Modle Derivative endpoint [GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) to retrieve the JSON manifest which will include the status of the translation for the entire document as well as the translation status of its individual 2D or 3D outputs.

Comment: In DerivativeWebhookEvent enum only one property is present ExtractionFinished and I can sucessfully implemented that but there is no property call ExtractionUpdated and I couldn't find a sample with perticular this webhook(ExtractionUpdated).