# Forge Viewer upload and translate Progress

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to view the progress status and information in client browser while upload & translation happening.
how to do it in forge viewer?
i want to show it with a progress bar. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the way how you want to implement it. Here are some references for you:

- Report file uploading progress from your web app's front side (webpage) to your backend server

  - By jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516883/7745569
  - By XMLHttpRequest.upload: [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest/3694435#3694435)
- Report file uploading progress from your web app's backend server to Forge service

  - Node.js: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/nailing-large-files-uploads-forge-resumable-api
  - .NET: https://github.com/yiskang/ForgeResumableUploadProgressDemo/blob/master/ForgeResumableUploadProgressDemo/Program.cs#L47
- For reporting Forge translation progress, you can take advantage of the WebHooks for Model Derivative API `extraction.updated`. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62531405/7745569

Once you got the progress data, you can use WebSocket to deliver the progress data from your server to the frontend side ( your viewer page), then use some technics like [bootstrap progress bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#progress), [JavaScript progress bar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp) and etc. to display your progress data.